# Objects contain same values but shouldn't

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I try to achieve an object inheritance, where each object shares the same functionality but contains different values/containers. Doing so I discovered a strange behavior; each individual object works like a charm but they all share the same options. Do clarify what I mean, I added a sample code.

What I want to do is read the data-value from each element and bind it to the options. Those are required inside some functions to work correctly!

```
<div class="first" data-value="first div"></div>
<div class="second" data-value="second div"></div>
<script>
    var original = {
        options: {
            value: null,
            factor: 13
        },

        init: function (container) {
            this.options.value = container.getAttribute('data-value');
        }
    };

    var variation = Object.create(original);
    variation.options.factor = 37;

    var firstDiv = Object.create(variation);
    var secondDiv = Object.create(variation);

    firstDiv.init(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]);
    secondDiv.init(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]);

    alert('firstDiv.options === secondDiv.options: ' + (firstDiv.options === secondDiv.options)); // but should be false!
</script>
```

Please note, that this just shows a little part of the actual objects. All the other parts are, in my opinion, irrelevant.

I hope it's clear what the problem is. Also that I use `Object.create()` on purpose.

Comment: I'm going to test this further but I think what is happening is that the Object.create is copying the original object, and that includes the reference to the object you created inside and then pointed "options" to it. basically its keeping the same reference, Object.create is only a shallow copy of the direct properties of the object.

Comment: @Sean_A91 You're basically correct, but `Object.create` doesn't copy anything at all; it sets the created object's *prototype* so that when you ask for properties that aren't defined on the object, the lookup escalates to check for a property on the prototype. In this case, the `this.options` lookup escalates to the prototype, because neither `firstDiv` nor `secondDiv` has a local `options` property. `firstDiv.otpions` and `secondDiv.options` are the exact same object; namely, `original.options`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> objects contain same values but shouldn't

They should, because you haven't changed the `options` property on `variation`, so it still points at the same object that the `original.options` points to.

When you do this:

```
var original = {
    options: {
        value: null,
        factor: 13
    },

    init: function (container) {
        this.options.value = container.getAttribute('data-value');
    }
};
```

Here's what you get in memory (some details omitted):

```
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−>| (Object.prototype) |<−+
original−−−>|  (object)  |   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                            |
            | __proto__  |−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
            | options    |−−−−−−−>|  (object)   |         |
            | init       |−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |    | __proto__   |−−−−−−−−−+
                             |    | value: null |
                             |    | factor: 13  |
                             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                             |
                             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                             +−−−−| (function) |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...where `__proto__` is a pseudo-property showing what the object's prototype is (specifically, the value of what the spec calls the object's internal `[[Proto]]` property). (On browsers, in ES2015, there is actually a `__proto__` accessor, but it shouldn't be used.)

Then when you do this:

```
var variation = Object.create(original);
```

You have:

```
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
variation−−>|  (object)  |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            | __proto__  |−−+
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                            |                              
         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
         |                     +−>| (Object.prototype) |<−+
         \  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
original−−−>|  (object)  |     |                          |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |                          |
            | __proto__  |−−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
            | options    |−−−−−−−>|  (object)   |         |
            | init       |−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |    | __proto__   |−−−−−−−−−+
                             |    | value: null |
                             |    | factor: 13  |
                             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                             |
                             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                             +−−−−| (function) |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

You can see how both `original` and `variation` are still pointing at the *same* options object.

If you want separate options objects, you have to create a new object. You could make `variation.options` use `original.options` as its prototype:

```
var variation = Object.create(original);
variation.options = Object.create(original.options);
```

...but then you'd have to do it *again* for `firstDiv` and `secondDiv`:

```
var firstDiv = Object.create(variation);
firstDiv.options = Object.create(variation.options);
var secondDiv = Object.create(variation);
secondDiv.options = Object.create(variation.options);
```

...which suggests we need to do something different.

You could have a function you use to do it:

```
function createVariation(source) {
    var v = Object.create(source);
    v.options = Object.create(source.options);
    return v;
}

var variation = createVariation(original);
var firstDiv = createVariation(variation);
var secondDiv = createVariation(variation);
```

...but you might look at constructor functions or maker functions, and a fairly typical pattern called the "extend" function (such as [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com) or [Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)).

Comment: Is it just me, or is there something vaguely unsettling about using prototypes as a poor-man's cloning mechanism.

Comment: @torazaburo: Not just you. :-)

Comment: Your ASCII diagramming skills are impressive. :)

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks. But in this case, my "answer the real question" skills are not. :-|

Comment: A bit better now, probably good enough to undelete, but I'm still not happy. But sadly out of time. :-) Anyone is free to grab as much or as little of the above and incorporate into a better answer. Later when I'm free, if there's a better answer, I'll delete this one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wrote an alternate answer as CW, but ultimately, you've done enough legwork here in deriving `createVariation` (and in general explanation) that I don't think there is likely to be  a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `firstDiv` nor `secondDiv` has its own `options` property. Both inherit `options` from `original`. You can test this by observing that all of the expressions below are `false`:

```
variation.hasOwnProperty("options") // false
firstDiv.hasOwnProperty("options")  // false
secondDiv.hasOwnProperty("options") // false
```

Your `init` function does `this.options.value = ...`, but consider for a moment only the expression `this.options`. You never create another `options` object, so when you ask for `firstDiv` or `secondDiv` for its `options` object, that escalates the `this.options` lookup to the `original` prototype object.

Thus, when you access the `options` property of either `firstDiv` or `secondDiv`, you are causing the property lookup to escalate to `original` (the first object in the prototype chain that really has an `options` property). This means that `firstDiv.options` and `secondDiv.options` are the exact same object (namely, `original.options`). Therefore, it follows that when you set `secondDiv.options.value`, you are also setting `firstDiv.options.value`.

The solution here is to ensure that `firstDiv` and `secondDiv` explicitly have their own `options` property. However, you also want that `options` value to itself inherit from `variation.options`, and you want `variation` to have its own `options` value as well, which inherits from `original.options`. [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757430/710446) addresses this in detail with his `createVariation` method:

```
function createVariation(source) {
    var v = Object.create(source);
    v.options = Object.create(source.options);
    return v;
}

var variation = createVariation(original);
var firstDiv = createVariation(variation);
var secondDiv = createVariation(variation);
```