# Element array from HTML table only consists of the last element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, html-table

everyone! I am trying to store the information from an HTML table to an array but the array consists of only the last element. When I print the element I am pushing to the array, there is no problem, but after the loop finishes the arrays elements are only the last entry. Here is the code and its output.

```
let entries = [];
let entryData = {
    takipKodu: "",
    guncelleme: "",
    talepSahibi: "",
    talepKonusu: "",
    talepDurumu: "",
    sonCevaplayan: "",
    onemDerecesi: ""
};

var entryTable = document.getElementsByClassName("table sindu-table ticket-list sindu_origin_table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tbody");

for(let i = 0; i < entryTable[0].rows.length; i++){
    let cells = entryTable[0].rows.item(i).cells;
    for(let j = 1; j < cells.length; j++){
        entryData[Object.keys(entryData)[j - 1]] = cells.item(j).innerText;
    }
    entries.push(entryData);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(entries[0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(entries[1]));
```

Here is the output when it is taken from inside the loop:

```
"{"takipKodu":"DYR-W7W-3UTA\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"fehmi özdemir","talepKonusu":"Orijinal Lead Time Bilgisi İçin Alan\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"fehmi özdemir","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (45)
    [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "{"takipKodu":"QLV-1U5-5S21\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"fehmi özdemir","talepKonusu":"ZMM04 üretim yeri ile bilgi kaydı led time eşit değil uyarısı\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"fehmi özdemir","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (45)
    [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "{"takipKodu":"G4Z-J95-QYUX\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"fehmi özdemir","talepKonusu":"ZMM04 sat olmasına rağmen sipmeke gelmeyen devamlı satıcı malzemeleri\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"fehmi özdemir","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (45)
    [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "{"takipKodu":"8R7-TEM-GB3M\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"fehmi özdemir","talepKonusu":"ZMM39 Mevcut Verilen Kaybolması\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"fehmi özdemir","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (45)
```

Here is the output when it is taken when the loop finishes:

```
"{"takipKodu":"HPM-9MH-BQ3A\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","talepKonusu":"COHV yuvarlama teslimata göre yapmalı\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (49)
"{"takipKodu":"HPM-9MH-BQ3A\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","talepKonusu":"COHV yuvarlama teslimata göre yapmalı\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (49)
"{"takipKodu":"HPM-9MH-BQ3A\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","talepKonusu":"COHV yuvarlama teslimata göre yapmalı\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (49)
"{"takipKodu":"HPM-9MH-BQ3A\n","guncelleme":"03 Mar 21","talepSahibi":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","talepKonusu":"COHV yuvarlama teslimata göre yapmalı\n","talepDurumu":"Yeni ","sonCevaplayan":"TUĞÇE PAŞALAR","onemDerecesi":"Yüksek\n"}", source:  (49)
```

Comment: `entryData` is an object you modify ... and change ... so the changes appear everywhere the object is in the array ... try `entries.push({...entryData});` to store a (shallow) copy of the object

Comment: The problem is that you only have **one** `entryData` object, which you repeatedly push to the array. (See the answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757277/objects-contain-same-values-but-shouldnt) for details.) You need to create a new object each time. Just put `entryData = { takipKodu: "", guncelleme: "", talepSahibi: "", talepKonusu: "", talepDurumu: "", sonCevaplayan: "", onemDerecesi: "" };` as the first statement in your outer `for` loop (you can remove the initializer from where you declare it too, just `let entryData;` is fine there).

Comment: `Object.keys(entryData)[j - 1]` is not guaranteed to work, since the key order is not guaranteed in Object